# bxSlider last slide empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have bxSlider integrated in an existing application showing three different slides.
Each slide contains a HTML canvas which is periodically updated with a new JCharts graph.
It works perfect! Only... the last slide does appear, but does not show the content of the canvas.

The following bxSlider element is used. In this case the canvas with id loadedClassesLineChart is showm, but does not show the graph. When i change the order of the

tags the content of the last canvas is not shown (although the canvas is shown an a pager is shown with 3 dots)

```
<ul class="bxslider" id="rdstats">
    <li><p style="background-color:rgb(231, 239, 252);margin-top: -4px;font-weight: bold;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;">Average CPU Load/CPUs</p><br/>
        <canvas id="cpuLoadRadarChart" width="200" height="200" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li><p style="background-color:rgb(231, 239, 252);margin-top: -4px;font-weight: bold;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;">Heapsize allocation</p><br/>
        <canvas id="heapSizeStackedBarChart" width="200" height="200" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li><p style="background-color:rgb(231, 239, 252);margin-top: -4px;font-weight: bold;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;">Loaded classes</p><br/> 
        <canvas id="loadedClassesLineChart" width="200" height="200" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></canvas>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When adding an extra empty `<li> </li>` after the last `</li>`  all three graphs are shown and the fourth empty slide is shown.

[bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) is started using the document ready function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#rdstats').each(function() {
        var _this = $(this).bxSlider({
            controls: false,
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            slidewidth: 200,
            slideMargin: 2});

        _this.mouseenter(function() {
            _this.stopAuto();
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            _this.startAuto();

        });

    });
```

What i have tried;

- UseCSS : false
- slideWidth : 200
- minSlides : different values
- maxSlides : different values
- adaptiveHeight: false

reproducable on FireFox, Safari and Opera

Anyone able to help me out on this one ?

Comment: can you reproduce the error in a fiddle?

Comment: Yup, here is an example. Stripped out the ajax calls so the data is now static.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/petervannes/9xsjwm5s/3/)

Comment: the external resources are not loaded properly due to wrong `Content-Type` because of that the fiddle is not working. load the fiddle and check the `console`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update fiddle. Now updated, fiddle should now also work for new sessions.

Comment: Worked on Safari, but when tested on Opera in indeed failed. Is a github issue which returns no content-type. Now added the external javascript using rawgit.com. Works on Opera too now. 

New link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/petervannes/9xsjwm5s/6/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64014/discussion-between-cerlin-boss-and-pcvnes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, the plugin `bxslider` clones some of the elements(`<li></li>`) which has canvas as child. So the canvas inside newly cloned element is **NOT** initialized using `ChartJS`

I have modified the code a little bit to support this.

```
// Refreshes bxslider with id "rdstats" with new data.
function refreshcpuLoadRadarChart() {

    // Replace the chart canvas element

    $('.cpuLoadRadarChart').replaceWith('<canvas class="cpuLoadRadarChart" width="200" height="200" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></canvas>');

    // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
    var ctx = $('.cpuLoadRadarChart').get(0).getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).Radar({"labels":["10:54","10:55","10:56","10:57","10:58","10:59","11:00","11:01","11:02","11:03","11:04","11:05","11:06","11:07","11:08","11:09"],"datasets":[{"label":"myserver","fillColor":"rgba(165,222,11,0.2)","strokeColor":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointColor":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointStrokeColor":"#fff","pointHighlightFill":"#fff","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","data":[0.03,0.01,0.2,0.53,0.34,0.2,0.43,0.28,0.17,0.28,0.24,0.32,0.2,0.45,0.42,0.15]}]}, {
        responsive: true,
        animation: false,
        tooltipFontSize: 10,
        tooltipTitleFontSize: 10,
        tooltipXOffset: 5,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleShowLabels: true,
        scaleSteps: 6,
        scaleStepWidth: 0.5,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        scaleFontSize: 10
    });


    setTimeout(function () {
        refreshcpuLoadRadarChart();
    }, 30000);

}


// Refreshes bxslider with id "rdstats" with new data.
function refreshHeapUsageBarChart() {


    $('.heapSizeStackedBarChart').replaceWith('<canvas class="heapSizeStackedBarChart" width="200" height="200" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></canvas>');
    $('.heapSizeStackedBarChart').each(function(pos,value){
    var ctx = $(value).get(0).getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).StackedBar({"labels":["myserver","myserver2","myserver3"],"datasets":[{"label":"Free %","fillColor":"rgba(255,255,255,0.7)","strokeColor":"rgba(255,255,255,1)","pointColor":"rgba(255,255,255,1)","pointStrokeColor":"rgba(255,255,255,1)","pointHighlightFill":"rgba(255,255,255,1)","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(255,255,255,1)","data":[50,50,50]},{"label":"Tenured Comm not Used%","fillColor":"rgba(165,222,11,0.7)","strokeColor":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointColor":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointStrokeColor":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointHighlightFill":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","data":[14,14,14]},{"label":"Tenured Used%","fillColor":"rgba(199,193,1,0.7)","strokeColor":"rgba(199,193,1,1)","pointColor":"rgba(199,193,1,1)","pointStrokeColor":"rgba(199,193,1,1)","pointHighlightFill":"rgba(199,193,1,1)","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(199,193,1,1)","data":[21,21,21]},{"label":"Survivor Comm not Used%","fillColor":"rgba(227,158,3,0.7)","strokeColor":"rgba(227,158,3,1)","pointColor":"rgba(227,158,3,1)","pointStrokeColor":"rgba(227,158,3,1)","pointHighlightFill":"rgba(227,158,3,1)","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(227,158,3,1)","data":[1,1,1]},{"label":"Survivor Used%","fillColor":"rgba(246,120,15,0.7)","strokeColor":"rgba(246,120,15,1)","pointColor":"rgba(246,120,15,1)","pointStrokeColor":"rgba(246,120,15,1)","pointHighlightFill":"rgba(246,120,15,1)","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(246,120,15,1)","data":[0,0,0]},{"label":"Eden Comm not Used%","fillColor":"rgba(254,83,38,0.7)","strokeColor":"rgba(254,83,38,1)","pointColor":"rgba(254,83,38,1)","pointStrokeColor":"rgba(254,83,38,1)","pointHighlightFill":"rgba(254,83,38,1)","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(254,83,38,1)","data":[11,11,11]},{"label":"Eden Used%","fillColor":"rgba(251,50,68,0.7)","strokeColor":"rgba(251,50,68,1)","pointColor":"rgba(251,50,68,1)","pointStrokeColor":"rgba(251,50,68,1)","pointHighlightFill":"rgba(251,50,68,1)","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(251,50,68,1)","data":[3,3,3]}]}, {
        responsive: true,
        animation: false,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 10,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        scaleOverride: true,
        tooltipXOffset: -25,
        tooltipFontSize: 10,
        tooltipTitleFontSize: 10
    });
})
    setTimeout(function () {
        refreshHeapUsageBarChart();
    }, 30000);
}

// Refreshes bxslider with id "rdstats" with new data.
function refreshLoadedClassesLineChart() {
    // Replace the chart canvas element

    $('.loadedClassesLineChart').replaceWith('<canvas class="loadedClassesLineChart" width="200" height="200" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"></canvas>');

    var ctx = $('.loadedClassesLineChart').get(0).getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).Line({"labels":["10:55","10:56","10:57","10:58","10:59","11:00","11:01","11:02","11:03","11:04","11:05","11:06","11:07","11:08","11:09","11:10"],"datasets":[{"label":"myserver","fillColor":"rgba(165,222,11,0.2)","strokeColor":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointColor":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","pointStrokeColor":"#fff","pointHighlightFill":"#fff","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(165,222,11,1)","data":[15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617,15617]}]}, {
        responsive: true,
        animation: false,
        tooltipFontSize: 10,
        tooltipTitleFontSize: 10,
        tooltipXOffset: 5,
        scaleShowLabels: true,
        scaleFontSize: 10
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        refreshLoadedClassesLineChart();
    }, 30000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('document ready');
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        controls: false,
        auto: true,
        autoHover: true,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        slidewidth: 200,
        slideMargin: 2,
        onSliderLoad: function(){

            refreshcpuLoadRadarChart();
            refreshHeapUsageBarChart();
            refreshLoadedClassesLineChart();
        }
    });
});
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xsjwm5s/8/)

Comment: Thanks a million ! Checked out the fiddle and works as i expected it would work initially.

Answer (score 1):

or simply set onSlideAfter reload where 3000 mean time how long to wait till reload from start (infinitiLoop must be false):

```
infiniteLoop: false,
onSlideAfter: function(){
   setTimeout(function(){_this.reloadSlider()},3000);
    }
```